# User badges disappears on questions on Android app

Tags: bug, badges, android-app

App version: 1.0.24

At times, the amount of badges a user has disappears and only the reputation is shown beside the username on a question (I haven't seen it happen on an answer yet). I can't figure out what causes this, it could display them one minute but the next question I visit they could be gone. If I logout I can see the badges fine, but if I log back in they could be gone again. And in two minutes time the badges might be back.

E.g. Logged in:

[image: Logged in]

Logged out:

[image: Logged out]

Logged in and a few minutes later:

[image: Logged in and a few minutes later]

Comment: What is that notification that you have 10 of?! :-P

Comment: Its the colornote app memo app, so its some stuff I am meant to do :P

Comment: Time to revisit old bug!.. Well, I couldn't repro (and never encountered) this before on Nexus 4/5, Android 4.4-6.0.1. Is it still affecting your side in newer version?